# How do I get the API V2 key in DialogFlow from a JSON file?

Tags: api, google-api, dialogflow-es

There are those who worked with DialogFlow after may 31? There API V2 now and the key needs to be obtained from a JSON file, in the Internet there is no information really

[Json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emkwE.png)

Comment: Did you solve your issue after generating the JSON key file? I have the same issue, I don't know how to get the credentials to use the REST API after getting that JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

from your agent setting click the `Service Account` link of `GOOGLE PROJECT` you will be redirected to `google cloud console`. Then create you key following the procedure given in this documentation https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/setup

after creating the `key` which is a `json` file you can download the file and use it to access the `dialogflow` api.

for your convenience I'm attaching snapshot of agent settings[image]